# Save the sequence of the written code to an export file in IPython?

Tags: python, ipython

I've written code and many functions inside IPython and now I want to export them to a file in a structured way as in a legible script.py. Is there any mechanism in Ipython to provide such an opportunity?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the `%save` magic:

> Save a set of lines or a macro to a given filename.

Comment: does it save all the written code in a file or how does it work ?

Comment: `%save filename line1-linen` will save your line 1 to line n input to a file named filename, type save? for more information.

Answer (score 0):

%save magic would work best for your current use case (where you have already written code and functions in ipython).

For future interactive programming sessions where you would like to save code later you might want to check out iPython notebook ([1](http://ipython.org/notebook.html)). Along with all existing iPython functionality and options for saving as plain python script or a reusable notebook, its great for interactive sessions.